# Can iPhone app connect to a bluetooth transmitter ( non iOs Device ) with A2DP Profile?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I want to create an iOS Application which will be listening to a streamed audio from a non iOS bluetooth hardware. This hardware will be transmitting the audio and iPhone App should play it. Is it possible to do this on iPhone ? Does iOs provides any support do do this with A2DP Profile. As far as I read Its not possible to connect iPhone to any non iOs device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible 
Because the iOS device supports only the A2DP source (i,e it can stream A2DP) and not A2DP Sink (i.e it cannot be listening to the stream)

Comment: As of iOS 6 (which came out after this was answered) it is now possible for iOS devices to act as a peripheral, which may make this possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well its possible.If You want to connect that device to iPhone you should register your device through apple. they will authenticate your device. Go through apple site for more details.

Comment: Well I have researched on this , Dennis Mathews's comments are right . iPhone can be the A2DP source but not the A2DP listener. And about that device , its a bluetooth trasmitter, How do i Register it with Apple.

Comment: @Bharat J:Then how can they say, u can create adhoc network using bluetooth and wifi with non iOS devices.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this using A2DP but you could use Apple's version of SPP to send Bluetooth data to the iPhone. The device sending to the iPhone would have to use Apple's Authentication Process, which requires the sending device to have Apple's Authentication Co-Processor chip (MFi). See https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/.